# Using a For Loop To Draw Lines Over a UISlider

Tags: ios, objective-c

I have a `UISlider` that I use to play a video, and I would like to put red "break indication" lines in my `UISlider` to visually show the user when the break is coming up, as visualized below. My slider has a set `.duration` property, and I have an array full of timestamps that contain the times that the video will need to pause for a break. I'm still getting the hang of iOS, so I don't know how to go about drawing the lines over `UISlider`'s. I would like it to appear similar to this:

[image]

In my research I've read in the Apple Docs that `UISlider` luckily provides a method to the sliders coordinates based upon a float value. This is perfect because now I can determine where in the slider I can draw the yellow line based upon the timestamps in the array, right?

So, I created a for loop to call the method and am (**attempting to**) draw a line.

The drawing the line part is what I'm having issues with. I've been reading through Apple's docs and other questions on this site, but I cannot seem to figure out the drawing logic. It draws just fine, the issue is that it's coordinates are all wrong. It draws and overlaps the majority of its lines in one specific location, the top left of my view. This is what I'm *trying* to do:

**Updated Code** In correlation with @Bannings answer (Many thanks to you).

```
    - (void)breakStarted:(NSNotification *)notification {

        self.lines = [NSMutableArray new];

        for (int i = 0; i < myArray.count; i++) {
            long long nanoSeconds = [[myArray.adMarkerTimes objectAtIndex:i] floatValue];
            float minutes = nanoSeconds / 60000000000;

            [self sliderThumbCenter:self.scrubberSliderView forValue:minutes];

            NSLog(@"Minute Readings: %f", minutes);
        }
    }

    - (float)sliderThumbCenter:(UISlider *)slider forValue:(float)value {

    CGRect trackRect = [slider trackRectForBounds:slider.bounds];
    CGRect thumbRect = [slider thumbRectForBounds:slider.bounds trackRect:trackRect value:value];
    CGFloat centerThumb = CGRectGetMidX(thumbRect);

    NSLog(@"Center Thumb / Line Placements on slider are: %f", centerThumb);

    [self.lines addObject:@(centerThumb)]; // Added the rect values to an array which we will loop through to draw the lines over the slider

    [self setNeedsDisplay];

    return centerThumb;
}
- (void)drawRect:(CGRect)rect {

    CGContextRef context = UIGraphicsGetCurrentContext();

    CGContextSetStrokeColorWithColor(context, [UIColor redColor].CGColor);
    CGContextSetLineWidth(context, 2);

    for (NSNumber *x in self.lines) {
        CGContextMoveToPoint(context, x.floatValue, 0);
        CGContextAddLineToPoint(context, x.floatValue, rect.size.height);
        CGContextStrokePath(context);
    }
}
```

I forgot to add: I'm manually converting CMTimeValue to seconds in the loop. That's what `myArray.adMarkerTimes`. Maybe I did that wrong...

Comment: "Here is where I'm lost. I have no idea how to make these values match up and draw? Draw what? Match up what? In any case, you cannot draw in `sliderThumbCenter`, so it's utterly unclear what you think you're up to.

Answer (score 5, accepted):

You can override the `drawRect` of UISlider.

```
- (void)drawRect:(CGRect)rect {
    CGContextRef context = UIGraphicsGetCurrentContext();

    CGContextSetStrokeColorWithColor(context, [UIColor redColor].CGColor);
    CGContextSetLineWidth(context, 2);


    CGContextMoveToPoint(context, 20, 0);
    CGContextAddLineToPoint(context, 20, rect.size.height);

    CGContextStrokePath(context);
}
```

or insert UIView to UISlider.

```
- (UIView *)lineViewForRect:(CGRect)rect {
    UIView *lineView = [[UIView alloc] initWithFrame:rect];
    lineView.backgroundColor = [UIColor redColor];
    return lineView;
}

- (void)viewDidLoad {
    [super viewDidLoad];

    [slider addSubview:[self lineViewForRect:CGRectMake(20, 0, 2, slider.bounds.size.height)]];
}
```

You also can set `lineView.layer.zPosition = 1`:

before:

[image]

after:

[image]

---

**EDIT:**
You can store lines in an array, and draw each in context.
It seems like this:

```
// YourSlider.m
- (void)addLineToX:(CGFloat)x {
    [self.lines addObject:@(x)];

    // This will cause drawRect to be called
    [self setNeedsDisplay];
}

- (void)drawRect:(CGRect)rect {
    CGContextRef context = UIGraphicsGetCurrentContext();

    CGContextSetStrokeColorWithColor(context, [UIColor redColor].CGColor);
    CGContextSetLineWidth(context, 2);

    for (NSNumber *x in self.lines) {
        CGContextMoveToPoint(context, x.floatValue, 0);
        CGContextAddLineToPoint(context, x.floatValue, rect.size.height);
    }

    CGContextStrokePath(context);
}
```

Comment: You sir, have helped me out tremendously, lol. Thank you man. I'm using your first solution, and for the first time the red line appears! The only problem I'm having is drawing it in correlation with the `sliderThumbCenter` method, which is where I'm calling `[self drawRect:thumbRect];`. Trying to use centerThumb but it is CGFloat. I can update my code in the OP if that didn't make sense.

Comment: @John You should never call this method(drawRect) directly yourself ! I edited, please tell me if that works

Comment: Thank you so much again for the insight and explanations, I really appreciate it. For some reason this time it draws all of the lines on top of each other... I updated my OP with my new code. Thank you again for your help!